# Combining Devise authenticate helpers with `OR` statements in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm currently using the Devise gem to handle user authentication.

There're helper methods that basically allows you to authenticate a user before they can access a certain route/view in your controller.

I.e. if you require `user_type_one`s to log in to access `/home`:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user_type_one!

   def home
     #stuff
   end
end
```

How would you go about making it so specified types of users can access the page.

So if I had three types of users, `user_type_one`, `user_type_two` and `user_type_three`, and I only want `user_type_one`s and `user_type_two`s to access `/home`, I want to do something like this.

`before_action :authenticate_user_type_one! || :authenticate_user_type_two!`

Comment: This three types of users are three entirely different model or they're inherited in some way? Why not defining another `before_action` to check which type of user the `current_user` belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise handles a lot of defaults for you and does a wonderful job of that, but when you need to start customizing behavior it can get really prickly about it. Particularly if you're pretty new to Rails development, often I think it's better to just write your own custom method that manually checks what you need it to check. Then as you get more familiar with Devise you can slowly learn about the built-in tools it might have, or internal hooks that you can hack into, to get the desired behavior more elegantly.

In specific, as a starting point I'd try writing a custom before_action:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_apple_or_orange_or_pear!

  def home
    stuff
  end

  protected

  def authenticate_apple_or_orange_or_pear!
    unless apple_signed_in? or orange_signed_in? or pear_signed_in?
      redirect_to go_away_and_never_return_path, alert: "You're not wanted here."
    end
  end

end
```

If I understand your need correctly, this should do what you're asking. It checks if any of the required account types are signed in, and if not, it redirects the visitor to a different path, blocking access to this controller.

If this is something you'll need across multiple controllers, you can also move this method definition into `application_controller.rb` and it will become available to all controllers that inherit from `ApplicationController` (which, typically, means all of them).